# Django functions vs database functions

Tags: django, postgresql

What is the best way to implement functions while writing an app in django? For example, I'd like to have a function that would read some data from other tables, merge then into the result and update user score based on it.
I'm using postgresql database, so I can implement it as database function and use django to directly call this function.
I could also get all those values in python, implement is as django function.
Since the model is defined in django, I feel like I shouldn't define functions in the database construction but rather implement them in python. Also, if I wanted to recreate the database on another computer, I'd need to hardcode those functions and load them into database in order to do that.
On the other hand, if the database is on another computer such function would need to call database multiple times.

Which is preferred option when implementing an app in django?

Also, how should I handle constraints, that I'd like the fields to have? Overloading the `save()` function or adding constraints to database fields by hand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a classic problem: do it in the code or do it in the DBMS? For me, the answer comes from asking myself this question: is this logic/functionality intrinsic to the data itself, or is it intrinsic to the application?

If it is intrinsic to the data, then you want to avoid doing it in the application. This is particularly true where more than one app is going to be accessing / modifying the data. In which case you may be implementing the same logic in multiple languages / environments. This is a situation that is ripe with ways to screw up—now or in the future.

On the other hand, if this is just one app's way of thinking about the data, but other apps have different views (pun intended), then do it in the app.

BTW, beware of premature optimization. It is good to be aware of DB accesses and their costs, but unless you are talking *big data*, or a very time sensitive UI, then machine-time, and to a lesser degree user-time, is less important than *your* time. Getting v1.0 out the door is often more important. As the inimitable [Fred Brooks](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Fred_Brooks) said, "Plan to throw one away; you will anyhow."